# How to disable cookbook synchronization with chef-client?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I would like to test/debug cookbooks. However, using chef-client to restart a chef run, this requires me to modify cookbooks, upload them to the chef server & synchronize cookbooks. 
I would like to be able to modify the cookbooks that were synchronized and stored in the cache, instead of having to upload every single little change I make at each iteration. Is this possible?

Thanks

tl;dr in chef-client, how to use the cached cookbooks instead of synchronizing them every time

Comment: This is useful when you want to add temporary logging to cookbooks without annoying the ops guys ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
chef-client --skip-cookbook-sync
```

Use cached cookbooks without overwriting local differences from the server. Use with caution. Useful for patching a set of cookbooks on a machine when iterating during development.
New in Chef Client 12.8.1.

https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html

Answer (score 1):

For Chef prior version 12 command is 
`chef-solo -z -o <cookbook_name>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use chef-client in local mode (see [here](https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/10/31/chef-client-z-from-zero-to-chef-in-8-5-seconds/) and [here](http://docs.chef.io/client/ctl_chef_client.html#run-in-local-mode)).

But beware that this uses everything from the local disk, also environments, roles and data bags.

For development, [test-kitchen](http://kitchen.ci) is the tool of choice, which might ease your pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a command something like this:

```
chef-client --local -o 'recipe[cookbookname::recipie]' --log_level info
```

or

```
chef-client -z -o 'recipe[cookbookname::recipie]' --log_level info
```